# Removing a child view from the parent view using a trigger

Tags: backbone.js

I have a backbone view that creates a child view when clicking a button like this:

```
    buttonClick: function () {
        var newView = new ChildView({ parent: this });
        this.$('.container').append(newView.render().$el);
    }
```

When finished, I want to be able to click a 'save' button that closes and removes this child view. So when I click the save button, I trigger an event:

```
saveClick: function () {
    //do some stuff and also remove that child view we added earlier
    this.trigger('removeChild');
}
```

Then I listen for this event in my child view like this:

```
   initialize: function (options) {
        this.parent = options.parent;
        this.listenTo(this.parent, 'removeChild', this.remove());
    },

    remove: function() {
        console.log("removing this view");
    }
```

But for some reason, it never makes it this far.  There is no error, it just doesn't do anything.

Is there anything critical I am missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should bind a function to listenTo like this:

```
this.listenTo(this.parent, 'removeChild', this.remove);
```

Here are some architectural tips:

- Don't pass parent to children, leave inter-module communication to models (this is a nice-to-have rather than a must)
- Recommended: Extend backbones View to be able to have an object or function of sub views, e.g:

```
// Note that if model or collection is not overriden, this parent's model and collection
// will be automaticaly passed down.
views: {
    '.js-some-selector': MyChildView,
    '.js-some-other-selector': {
        view: SomeOtherView,
        options: function() {
            someOption: this.somethingFromParent
        }
    }
}
```

Note: that like the views variable, options should be able to be an object or function, it is
a function when you want to access something from the parent (through `this`).

Or it can be a function:

```
views: function() {
    var views = {};

    // Because it is a function you can conditionally add views:
    if (this.isLoggedIn) {
        views['.js-account-summary'] = AccountSummaryView;
    }

    return views;
}
```

Then you should:

- Override `.remove` so that it removes subviews
- Create a `.render` method which renders the parent, and then the sub views
- Nice to have: Create a `.serialize` method which is responsible for passing a context object to your template render method

Comment: Oh I see, and then add 'this.remove();' in the remove function?  thanks

Comment: You don't need to override remove at all in this case unless you are doing something special. And if you are you should still call the parent like `return Backbone.View.remove.call(this);` or  `return Backbone.View.remove.apply(this, arguments);` Otherwise the view won't get removed as you have stopped the backbone remove code from being called by overriding the method.